# How can I change the Storyboard animation for modal in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, ios5, storyboard

I am quite new to Xcode coding and I have been using Storyboard for along time, if you know when you link a button to a view and select the option "Modal" it will make a link with the animation of the new view coming up from the bottom. I was wondering if it was possible to change the animation to the new view coming from the right. I am sorry this question was so brief, if you need more info just ask me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you select the segue and look at the Attributes Inspector (on the right side of the window), you will see a pop-up menu labeled Transition.  This menu lists the available transition styles for the segue:

[image]

- Cover Vertical
- Flip Horizontal
- Cross Dissolve
- Partial Curl

If you want a different style of transition, you will need to use a different type of segue.  If you have a `UINavigationController` hosting your source view controller (the one that contains the button), you can use a Push segue, which slides the new view in from the right.  If you don't have a navigation controller or don't like the Push segue animation, you'll have to implement a custom segue to change the animation.

Answer (score 1):

More on custom segues

[Custom Segue- Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html)

[Custom Segue + CATransition](http://blog.jambura.com/2012/07/05/custom-segue-animation-left-to-right-using-catransition/)

-anoop

Comment: more details about what those links are all about on SO would have been nice nonetheless its what i was looking for thanks